# Replacing duplicate elements inside 2D List from other List

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, tuples

I have this code of replacing duplicate elements in 2D list but only first index are changing duplicates and the other index elements keep shuffling. Thankyouuuuu have a great day!!

```
import random
ch = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',]
my_tuple_1 = [['a', 'b', 'b', 'd'],['a', 'c', 'c', 'd']]
my_set = set()
my_result = [tuple(ele if ele not in my_set and not my_set.add(ele) else random.choice(ch)for ele 
in y ) for y in my_tuple_1]
print("The tuple after replacing the values is: ")
print(my_result)
#OUTPUT - > [('a', 'b', 'e', 'd'), ('d', 'c', 'd', 'f')]
#EXTECTED OUTPUT - > [('a', 'b', 'e', 'd'), ('a', 'c', (get random from ch), 'd')]
```

Comment: Could you clarify how the input maps to the output?

Comment: on my_tuple_1 i want to replace 1 of duplicate elements every rows from getting random elements  in ch List. On my output now the first row only changing duplicates that are not changing any of elements, which is correct. But the second row all elements are changing instead of one of c's in second row, which is not supposed to.

Comment: __and not my_set.add(ele)__ why are you checking this  ? This will always return True.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_result = []
for y in my_tuple_1:
  my_set = set()
  my_tuple = ()
  for ele in y:
    if ele not in my_set:
      my_tuple += (ele,)
      my_set.add(ele) 
    else:
      random_ch = random.choice(list(set(ch) - set(my_tuple)))
      my_tuple += (random_ch,)
      my_set.add(random_ch)

  my_result.append(my_tuple)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: First of all you are using reserved keyword for storing tuple, instead you can use tuple_, secondly what will happen if random.choice pick the same element that you have removed using set ? For example if you have ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'] and you convert it into set then what if random.choice selects 'c' again then your output will be {'a', 'b','c'} but expected should be {'a', 'b', 'c', get_random_from(ch)_excluding__c__}

Comment: @Deepak Tripathi Thanks for the remark. I have edited the answer.

Comment: ohhh thanks a lot now i get it, the other problem you said also i worked on now but this code above is perfectly working now thanks a lot @DeepakTripathi :))  what a life saver